# facebook error code 102

Tags: php, facebook

i have developed a php based app for facebook. now i need to push data into the user's stream.
for that I have to implement the xd_receiver.html cross domain communication channel. 
now the problem i am facing is i have done exactly as mentioned in the documentation, but in the console log, I am getting `Error Code 102`
It says:

```
API failed with error code = 102
Bad session key, clear it
```

It however successfully pulls information like uid and name successfully.

If there is any other way for me to easily push status / feed updates, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using the API key from one of my other apps. Changed the API key and the bad session problem was resolved.